# Setting a limit to how far my player can move in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

If I want my player to only be able to run a short distance before stopping, or in this example climb an object a set distance before falling back to the ground, how would I approach implementing that?

My main idea was to use a `while` loop where I have a set time value and then use `Time.time` to  make sure that once my player has been climbing for 3 seconds, turn the `moveVertically` bool **false.**

The other idea was to have a `Raycast` shoot forward from the center of my player and if it no longer hits an object in front of it then my player falls down, but that felt pretty clunky and not smooth at all.

```
// Inside Update, and outside of isGrounded
bool raycast1 = (Physics.Raycast(transform.position + transform.up * -0.8f, transform.forward, 0.6f));
bool raycast2 = (Physics.Raycast(transform.position + transform.up * .5f, transform.forward, 0.6f));

if (raycast1 && raycast2) // Two Raycasts that shoot a short distance forward
{
    moveVertically = true;
}

if (moveVertically)
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        controller.Move(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * verticalSpeed); // Climb up an object
    }
}
```

So essentially if my character controller component is 2f in height (default height) and I have a climbable object that is 10f in height, my player should only be able to climb less than half of that before not being able to any further and then falling to the ground.

Comment: `My main idea was to use a while loop where I have a set time value and then use Time.time to make sure that once my player has been climbing for 3 seconds, turn the moveVertically bool false.

The other idea was to have a Raycast shoot forward from the center of my player and if it no longer hits an object in front of it then my player falls down, but that felt pretty clunky and not smooth at all.` -> what did not work on the first? I think before coming to an implementation you seem to first have to figure out what behavior you actually want

Comment: I don’t think any of your 2 suggested approach’s will work. If you have a while loop in the update method, it will block until all time passes without doing more updates (unless you use a coroutine). And the raycast thing, I don’t get how it would ever work

Comment: I've only ever used `Time.time` for a `coroutine` to do with a dash cooldown so I don't know if that's actually a normal way of going about this.

Comment: well `Time.time` is just the time in seconds since app start ... totally up to you what you do with that value ;) As said .. I think before you go into implementation details you first have to get very clear what exactly is supposed to happen ... do you want to go time-based, distance-based, raycast-based .. currently you throw all those together into the options pool ... so it is a bit hard to provide a solid answer if you don't even  know yourself what the expected outcome is exactly

Comment: I'm actually not sure what kind of methods would work here. I would really like to avoid using a coroutine but the Raycast approach is a bit confusing currently.

Comment: @askinuni64 any of those could be made to "work" .. the question is what exactly do you **want**?

Comment: @derHugo I'm currently trying to make it raycast-based, and my idea is to use `Vector3.down` and then as I'm climbing, check to see how far off the ground I am, and if  the `Raycast` no longer detects ground, fall down. But that doesn't seem too good

Comment: I'm currently testing my idea out, I'm going to get the values just right with `DrawRay` and then see what happens

Comment: well falls to ground .. only doing this by raycast would be result in 1 frame climbing -> reaching max, 1 frame falling -> not max anymore -> 1 frame climbing etc ... you would probably want to go physics based and actually keep falling until you hit the ground ... and if your ground is anyway always on a fix height you could also simply check your height without a raycast

Comment: Yeah I'm using `Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, 3.5f)` which will need a bit of adjusting and so far it works, but now if I climb to the top of an object and it is just outside of the `3.5f` range above, my character will stutter/shake a lot and refuse to climb because now the bool is false. So now I need to go and try and fix that

Answer (score -1):

You've described two different things here.  If your goal is to set an arbitrary climbing height, you can use some way to mark colliders as 'climbable' and just design your levels so that the colliders end at a certain height from the ground.  It sounds, though, that what you really want is something more like an 'exhaustion' mechanic where your character can only climb for a certain amount of time before losing their grip.  You would then tune the exhaustion time to limit their total possible climb height for level design purposes.

In the latter case, I'd recommend looking at Celeste for a good example of a climbing exhaustion mechanic.  The Celeste mechanic actually allows resetting exhaustion pretty frequently and so doesn't set a total height that can be climbed; the game instead uses other obstacles to limit vertical progress.  However the core idea can be tweaked to whatever limits you want.

For implementation, you want to keep track of a 'climbing' state and have a timer that starts upon entering that state.  You can have it apply only while climbing (and reset as soon as climbing stops) or you could do something with a more persistent state where the exhaustion decrements while not climbing and increments while climbing.  There are also various hysteresis thresholds you could set, like a cooldown time before you can start climbing again or escalating exhaustion based on time spent climbing, possibly tying into a 'stamina' system that impacts other mechanics.

In short, I'd look up the concept of state machines (the concept, not necessarily any formal implementation of them) and look into how to model the various states involved in climbing and losing your grip.  This will likely naturally connect to animation states related to these logical game states.

Comment: Do you think it's a bad idea to use multiple Raycasts or is there no limit to how many you want to use? My current idea is to have three total Raycasts in two different if statements to add the "exhaustion/limit" feature.

Comment: @askinuni64, If you're talking about detecting the wall for determining climbing state, it's common to use three (at top, middle and bottom of the character hitbox, vertically.)  This lets you detect states like sliding off the bottom of a wall (you lose attachment if you slide too far) and sometimes stuff like a climb-over mechanic (if you get high enough climbing the wall, you transition into climbing over the edge and standing.)  The cost of raycasts is fairly low, so use however many you need for the kind of state transitions you want.

Comment: This somehow ended up in the VLQ queue. I have no clue why because it really isn't - I don't have the domain knowledge to know whether it's a correct answer or not, but it appears to be a good-faith attempt to answer the question.

Comment: Possibly there's an expectation for answers to include code?  Character controllers and state models are a complicated topic and there are tons of different ways to implement them, so it's hard to suggest even a basic concrete implementation without understanding the larger context of the OP's code.  Presumably they already have some form of character controller that these mechanics would fit into.